# External Hard Drive needs format 

Tags: external-hard-drive, data-recovery

I recently bought a new ADATA external Classic hard drive 500 GB. I have transferred around 29 GB of data on it till I install my new Windows 7 operating system. After some work with the hard drive (copying / deleting ... files). I closed it for some reason and it couldn't open again asking me to format. I don't want to format the hard drive, I have important data I need. Is there a way I can retrieve my data? Is Recover My Files program from GetData a right choice?

Part 2 of my question: Why might such thing happen (require format to open), is it the hard drive problem or is it just a corrupted file or folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to my problem was actually buying this amazing software: DeRescue Data Recovery Master. Don't try to get this product for free ! It's only $60 and get's you the folders in their directories the way they were instead of searching for hours for file extensions (like the way Recover My Files work) . This is a professional software that is the solution to my problem!!!! :D

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to do is nothing.

The second thing to do is make an exact duplicate of the drive.  If you only have Windows to work with, I don't know the best answer for tools, but I do know that you will want to purchase another drive to copy the first onto unless you have a spare lying around (I'm wierd, I have 12 spares lying around).  If you don't have a tool you trust to copy the drive without writing to it AT ALL, including updating timestamps and the like, then skip this step and go to the next one.

You may end up sending the defective drive to a data recovery specialist.  Given the circumstances you describe, I suspect they'll be able to get your data back without too much cost, but you should expect to pay for it.

The last thing you want to do is write or make any change whatsoever to the drive that is experiencing problems.

Comment: That's not exactly what I need. i was asking about appropriate software for file recovery or actually folder recover (to get the directories as they were instead of getting files by extension)

thanks